# Access element in recently loaded XUL document

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I'm developing a Firefox extension and need to do the following:

- load a page
- get an element from this page
- modify the attributes from this element

The code I would like to work looks like this:

```
gBrowser.loadURI("chrome://myExtension/content/myPage.xul");
let button = content.document.getElementById("myExtension-theButton");
button.setAttribute("oncommand", "myFunction(withParams)");
```

But when I run this, button is null. (Maybe loadURI returns too early and the document isn't fully loaded, yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to that gBrowser:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', dofunc, false);

function dofunc(e) {
    var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
    var doc = win.document;
    if (doc.location == 'chrome://myExtension/content/myPage.xul') {
        let button = content.document.getElementById("myExtension-theButton");
        button.setAttribute("oncommand", "myFunction(withParams)");
        gBrowser.removeEventListener('DOMCOntentLoaded', dofunc, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hoped that I do not need a listener for that. When the loadURI would be blocking, everything would be fine. But your solution works, thanks.

Comment: like you wanted loadURI to be syncronus? like your code after loadURI line will happen after page load? just want to give you both solution so you can learn, if there is one im not sure of a sync solution